Numbering Equations in a Closed Bracket
I want to number equations in a closed bracket as seen in this figure.

I tried fer things but non of them work.

You can use aligned to construct the inner equation alignment and numbering, surrounding it with \left\{...\right\} for the braces:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% \seteqnum[<optional label>]
\NewDocumentCommand{\seteqnum}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\textup{\tagform@{#1}}}% <label> supplied
    {\incr@eqnum \print@eqnum}% <label> not supplied
}
\NewCommandCopy{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

For example, see~\eqref{eq:last}:
\[
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      a x^2 + b x + c &= d               & \seteqnum \\
              a x + b &= c x^2 + d       & \seteqnum[a] \\
                    a &= b x^2 + c x + d & \seteqnum \ltxlabel{eq:last}
    \end{aligned}
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}

You have to set the equation numbers manually via \seteqnum. The optional argument allows you to insert a numbering of your own. However, such numbering can't be referenced (without more coding). \ltxlabel can be used to label the numbered equations and are then referenceable via \eqref, if needed.

Thanks, when I try to reference the equations via \eqref it gives me an error in overleaf!

@NickCooper: How can I replicate your issue. Can you provide a setup (code) that I can test?

I get the error when I use the packege: \usepackage{hyperref}!

Without this package it works fine!

@NickCooper: When I add hyperref to my example (after amsmath), it compiles fine with a hyperlink. So, it's not possible to replicate your issue with just that information.

Also, another issue that I have is that when I refer to Equation (a) in your code, it does not give me anything! But the last equation is fine!

@NickCooper: Indeed. That's my reference to "[needs] more coding."

I don't think this is a good way to set down equations, but it's your choice.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignednum}{b}{%
  \sbox0{$\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}$}%
  \begin{equation}
  \left\{\,
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\wd0+3em}}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
  \begin{fleqn}
  \noindent
  \begin{align}#1\end{align}
  \end{fleqn}
  \end{minipage}
  \,\right\}
  \notag\end{equation}%
}{\stepcounter{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[35][1-4]
\begin{alignednum}
a+b&=c \label{a}\\
d+e&=f \label{b}\\
g+h&=i \label{c}
\end{alignednum}
\lipsum[42][1-4]

\eqref{a}, \eqref{b}, \eqref{c}

\end{document}


How to do it in a more standard way? Compare the following settings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignednum}{b}{%
  \sbox0{$\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}$}%
  \begin{equation}
  \left\{\,
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\wd0+3em}}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
  \begin{fleqn}
  \noindent
  \begin{align}#1\end{align}
  \end{fleqn}
  \end{minipage}
  \,\right\}
  \notag\end{equation}%
}{\stepcounter{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\section{Your proposed way}

\lipsum[35][1-4]
\begin{alignednum}
a+b&=c \label{a}\\
d+e&=f \label{b}\\
g+h&=i \label{c}
\end{alignednum}
\lipsum[42][1-4]

\eqref{a}, \eqref{b}, \eqref{c}

\section{A more standard way}

\begin{subequations}\label{global}
\lipsum[57]{1-4}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
a+b&=c \label{local-a}\\
d+e&=f \label{local-b}\\
g+h&=i \label{local-c}
\end{empheq}
\lipsum[58][1-2]
\end{subequations}

The system~\eqref{global} is very important; look, in particular, at equation~\eqref{local-b}.

\end{document}



Thanks, what do you mean by this is not a good way to set down equations!

@Nick Cooper: It's definitely a non-standard way to do this

@NickCooper I've never seen it. Please, note that I added \stepcounter{equation} before \ignorespacesafterend, which I forgot to do.

Thanks, I know that putting equations in closed bracket is not standard, but I need this to label some equations in a set of equations!

@NickCooper I added an alternative form.
